# android Tab fragment. Map not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

All my tabs work properly and looks like the map is trying to work (I see the Google logo in the bottom left, but map is not rendering.

[image: Phome]

Here are my Fragment activity:

```
public class BarberMapActivity extends Fragment implements 
OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public static BarberMapActivity newInstance() {
        BarberMapActivity fragment = new BarberMapActivity();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.barber_map_tab, null, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(34.0052982, -83.9888499);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
 }
```

Here is my map layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".shopResult.tabs.BarberMapActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add the SHA-1 into your google developer console
[google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis)

Comment: It was actually the package name that was incorrect. So you gave you the answer since it got me in the right direction.